# Are my disks compromised?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

Is it normal? Look in "other devices".

I used `lvm` during installation.

[image]

Comment: What exactly should we see there ?

Comment: What exactly you mean by that?

Comment: Just.. is normal looking at the picture? i mean it's normal to have other devices, blocked?

Comment: @tealXX They're not blocked, they're block devices. Which is to say, they're disks.

Comment: From what we see here you have perfectly healthy system with swap and root partition , which in linux world are called block devices, on 1 tb drive and 16 gb drive, which is probably your live usb disk ?

Comment: Thank you very much Serg.. no it's not the usb, it's windows recovery

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of LVM tool for more insights.
LVM can be installed this way

```
sudo apt-get -y install lvm2
```

[image]

and gparted
[image]

If you are using LVM- then it will always shows 100% full even it is not 100% full.